# How can I use a numpy array with index values to set elements of another numpy array to 0?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ros

I am taking a numpy array `proc_ranges` and finding which values are +/- 5 apart in value. I then want to set elements within a certain range of those indexes to 0. I have the following two numpy arrays, where the elements are the indexes of the elements of `diff_array` that are > 5 or < -5.

```
diff_array = np.diff(proc_ranges)
bubble_to_the_right_arr = np.where(diff_array > 5)
bubble_to_the_left_arr = np.where(diff_array < -5)
```

I am using the following lines to set index ranges within `proc_ranges` to 0:

```
proc_ranges[bubble_to_the_right_arr-bubble_size:bubble_to_the_right_arr+bubble_size] = 0
proc_ranges[bubble_to_the_left_arr-bubble_size:bubble_to_the_left_arr+bubble_size] = 0
```

These lines are giving me an error as you cannot add or subtract a tuple from an int. `bubble_size` is just a constant int. Basically I am trying to set multiple index ranges within `proc_ranges` to 0, but I am not sure how to set values using a tuple as an index parameter.

Comment: Look at `bubble_to_the_right_arr`.  Make sure you understand exactly what it is!  (re)Read the docs of `np.nonzero`.

Comment: Besides this difficulty of subtracting a number from a tuple, you have the problem of constructing slices from arrays or lists.  A slice only works with numbers, e.g. `[1:10]`.  You can't define a slice with a list or arrays, e.g. `[[1,2,3]:[4,5,6]]`.